# Dockerized http services are not accessible from nordvpn meshnet

Tags: vpn, docker, routing, linux-networking, docker-compose

I am setting up a home server (using ubuntu server 22.04) with several services deployed on various ports.
For example, my homepage server is deployed on port 3000.

When on the local network:

- Ssh access is OK
- Http services deployed directly on the server are OK
- Http services deployed via docker with a bridge network are OK

When I use nordvpn meshnet:

- Ssh access is OK
- Http services deployed directly on the server are OK
- Http services deployed via docker with a bridge network are NOT ACCESSIBLE

Here is the docker compose for my homepage server

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  homepage:
    image: ghcr.io/gethomepage/homepage:latest
    container_name: homepage
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /config:/app/config
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      PUID: $PUID
      PGID: $PGID
    networks:
      - homepage_net

networks:
  homepage_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is my main ethernet interface:

```
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.XXX  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.XXX
        ether XXX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 257310280  bytes 326111324526 (326.1 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 157444527  bytes 168981936261 (168.9 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf3a00000-f3a20000
```

Here is the nordlynx network interface (Nordvpn's meshnet features creates it):

```
nordlynx: flags=81<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING>  mtu 1420
        inet XXX  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination XXX
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 236544852  bytes 298874606486 (298.8 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 52996561  bytes 13275751612 (13.2 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 34313 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here are my routes:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s25
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-9066eab87b15
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-e7a37ce3a7bd
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-e6e5e235ac3b
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-64f3f670aea1
172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-f624ee4026b8
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-90ed8d1cb5ca
192.XXX         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s25
```

EDIT:

Here is my nordvpn whitelist:

```
Allowlisted subnets:
        172.0.0.0/8
        100.0.0.0/8
        192.168.50.0/24
```

Since it is working on the local network, I think it might be a docker or routing issue.
I am pretty much a noob when it comes to system administration and networking. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't censor RFC1918 addresses.

Comment: I have the following in my whitelist: 172.0.0.0/8, 100.0.0.0/8, 192.168.50.0/24, is that not enough ?

Comment: I have added the following: 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 and it is not working either

Comment: Are you sure nordvpn allows traffic from the internet to a host? Many commercial vpn providers only allow outbound traffic over the vpn and not to run a workload or service for incoming traffic.

Comment: Well, I have a netdata process which is deployed directly on the host (not through docker) and it works properly through meshnet. So I guess dockerized services should be accessible too, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;WR - Enable the local network access permission in Meshnet on the Docker machine for peers who should be able to access the containers.

```
nordvpn meshnet peer local allow [command options] <peer_hostname>|<peer_nickname>|<peer_ip>|<peer_pubkey>
```

e.g.

```
nordvpn meshnet peer local allow adam.frydrych-everest.nord
```

We’re currently aware of an issue that if a Docker container port has been exposed to the host machine, it is still required to provide peers with local network access permission within Meshnet in order to access services inside Docker containers.

This is caused by Docker exposing ports by inserting iptables rules in the PREROUTING chain.

Example of such rule:

```
-A DOCKER ! -i br-72e949c2a2f0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8004 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.24.0.2:80
```

This means that when a packet enters the INPUT/FORWARD chain, it will be seen as having the IP address of the Docker-defined network within the 172.16.0.0/16 subnet (172.24.0.2 in this case). Because of that, Meshnet will drop such packets according to the preset rules that are set to drop traffic destined for private IP ranges, such as:

```
169.254.0.0/16
192.168.0.0/16
172.16.0.0/12
10.0.0.0/8
```

In other words, Meshnet treats the Docker IP range as a local network, and that’s why you need to set local network access with the following command:

```
nordvpn meshnet peer local allow [command options] <peer_hostname>|<peer_nickname>|<peer_ip>|<peer_pubkey>
```

Note:

> Here is my nordvpn whitelist:

> ```
>     Allowlisted subnets:
>     172.0.0.0/8
>     100.0.0.0/8
>     192.168.50.0/24
> ```

This allowlist only applies to NordVPN connections and does not change Meshnet permissions.

If Docker or a local subnet record has been added to the allowlist, make sure to get rid of it with the following command:

```
nordvpn allowlist remove command [command options] [arguments...]
```

Additionally, if NordVPN is connected, make sure that LAN discovery is turned on with the following:

```
nordvpn set lan-discovery on
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your detailed answer. I've connected to my server and entered the command to allow local access to my macos client. Unfortunately it does not seem to work. I've tried this with a linux client too, but to no avail.
Maybe I'll try to manually create the route you described.
Is there any ongoing work to fix this issue ?

Comment: The server is the main meshnet device, maybe that's the issue ?

Comment: Meshnet doesn't have a main device, per se. 

Making sure we're on the same page. On your server (e.g. matthieusb-alps.nord), you have enabled local network access for your client devices (e.g. matthieusb-everest.nord), correct? Can you see that permission enabled when you input this command: `nordvpn meshnet peer list`?

Comment: I connected to my ubuntu server (Aka matthieusb-himalayas.nord) and enabled local network access for my macos client (Aka matthieusb-alps.nord).
Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Here is output of the peer list command (Executed on the server, himalayas):
Hostname: matthieu-himalayas.nord
Nickname: -
IP: 100.113.29.78
Public Key: XXX

Local Peers:
Hostname: matthieu-alps.nord
Nickname: -
Status: connected
IP: XX
Public Key: XX
OS: macos
Distribution: 14.3.0
Allow Incoming Traffic: enabled
Allow Routing: disabled
Allow Local Network Access: enabled
Allow Sending Files: enabled
Allows Incoming Traffic: enabled
Allows Routing: disabled
Allows Local Network Access: enabled
Allows Sending Files: disabled
Accept Fileshare Automatically: disabled

Comment: Moving forward, I'm going to need logs. Here is a link to a guide: https://support.nordvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/20379326742161-How-to-get-connection-logs-on-Linux 

Also, if you don't mind, the output of `ip route show table all`, and `iptables-save` commands would be useful. You can send me the output in a DM. EDIT: Or you can send them to NordVPN support and let me know the ticket number, as I'm not sure if you will be able to DM me here.

Comment: I think we can open a conversation here. But I will also contact the support. I will try to provide details as soon as possible.

Comment: I have provided the information you requested to the nordvpn support. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please remove `172.0.0.0/8` and `100.0.0.0/8` from your allowlist with `nordvpn allowlist remove command [command options] [arguments...]`. It's a little counterintuitive as it disables connections both for the VPN and Meshnet.

Comment: Done, but the problem persists

Comment: In this case, can you please set lan discovery to on with `nordvpn set lan-discovery on`? Let me know if this works, sorry for the drawn out troubleshooting.

Comment: Looks like with the `nordvpn meshnet peer local allow` and `nordvpn set lan-discovery on` commands, it finally works.
Thanks a lot for your help !